# How does one get text from inside of parenthesis in c++?

Tags: c++

I have something like: ("Today is a good day to die.\n") and it should look like: Today is a good day to die. Not sure of the syntax that should be used to get it. This is a function of a program that I am trying to write. It should pull the text, as mentioned above, from main labeled s. The code I currenly have is:

```
std::string parenthetical(const std::string& s){
    const string foo;
    const auto start = find(foo.cbegin(), foo.cend(), '(');
    const auto finish = find_if(start, foo.cend(), [](char i) {
        if (i == '(') {
            count++;
        }else if (i == ')') {
            count--;
        }return count <= 0;});
    return 0;
}
```

I am unable to get the compiler to accept the count. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have tried a while loop with a switch. I was thinking there must be an easier way to do this.

Comment: Please post your code, we cant help you if we don't know what you have tried so far. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for info on how to properly provide an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do what you are trying to do. (Based on what I can gather from your question)

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::string str = "(\"Today is a good day to die.\")";
    std::cout<<str<<std::endl;
    str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(),
                             str.end(),
                             [](char x){ return (x == '(' || x==')');}),
              str.end());
    std::cout<<str<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

See [HERE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) for reference.

EDIT:

Try this within the context of the code your provided

```
std::string parenthetical(const std::string& s){
    std::string str(s);
    str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(),
                             str.end(),
                             [](char x){ return (x == '(' || x==')');}),
              str.end());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That looks much better than: while (s.good())
 {
  switch (s.get())
  {
  case '(': ++s; break;
  case ')': --s; break;
  case '\n': return s == 0;
  }
  
  if (s < 0)
  {
   while (s.good())
   if (s.get() == '\n')
    return false;
  }

Comment: This line: s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char s){ return (s == '(' || s == ')'); }), s.end()); is giving me an overload with the period here: s.erase  Any ideas on how to get rid of it?

Comment: An overload? I'm assuming you mean compiler error or exception thrown?

Comment: No. It clearly was giving me an overload error. With the new code, it works fine. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The issue was that you were trying to call s.erase(...) on a string that you held via a const reference.